# Django & twill - session cookies not being set

Tags: python, django, testing, cookies, twill

I'm testing a django application with [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/), and [django-test-utils](http://ericholscher.com/projects/django-test-utils/), and it's not logging me in.

I think it's not setting the django session cookie. I go to a webpage (in twill) that calls `request.session.set_test_cookie()`, and after that call returns, `twill.show_cookies()` (which should print out the cookies), shows no cookies. In another page/view, `request.session.test_cookie_worked()` returns `False`.

*Oddly*, another page, calls `request.set_cookie(...)` to manually set a cookie, and that works. `twill.show_cookies()` shows that cookie. So some cookies are working, but the session middleware just doesn't seem to be working...

What could be going on? How do I get the django session cookie to be set in twill?

Some other people have had similar problems, [example on django-users](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg20583.html), [comment about cookies on another twill/django script](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/665/#c2507)

Comment: are the client and server in the same machine? if not check the date/time of the server

Answer (score 0):

As F.C. said, if the client and server are different machines with non-matching times (or even possibly timezones), you may end up with cookie expiration problems.

I just double-checked [the code for `set_test_cookie()`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L78), and it looks like it sets that value pretty normally. Are you certain that the page you are having trouble with isn't returning an error (and thus not setting the `test_cookie`)? There are a whole bunch of ways that could happen, but off the top of my head:

- Twill may not send a `Host` header your app requires
- Twill may not send a `referer` your app requires
- Twill may not support compression/encryption/multipart/something else
- Twill may not perfectly emulate a browser in some other fashion
- One of your other middlewares may require some combination of the above

Double-check your other middlewares. Try making a blank project that ONLY tests this issue. A blank project with just the admin enabled should be enough. If you can replicate it in a minimal configuration, we can be more helpful with chasing down the bug.